# Interact with the five millions of dots on a screen

Tags: graphics, html5-canvas, visualization, 2d-games

We need to display 5 millions of dots (or very simple graphics objects) on a screen at the same time and we want to interact with each of the dots (e.g., change their colors or drag/drop them).
To achieve this, we usually run a for-loop through 5 millions items in the worst case O(N) to access and change the states of the dot, according to the mouse coordinates (x, y).  Due to the huge number of the objects, this approach causes lots of overhead (we have to run the for-loop of five millions whenever a user selects a dot). I have already tested this approach but it was almost impossible to make an interactive tool with this. Is there anyway to rapidly and efficiently access the dots without running the million for-loop and causing this performance problem?

Comment: How big is the canvas?

Comment: Full screen (1980x1080) or bigger than the HD resolution. Thanks!

Comment: You could use some partitioning algorithm like [quadtrees](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/03/21/javascript-quadtree-implementation/) to reduce the amount of iterations over the objects. But 5 millions ( 5 000 000 ) of objects is massive. For instance, a native device with resolution of (1920x1080) have 2 073 600 pixels. Unless your application needs to run in resolutions of 4K or above this doesn't make any sense. Even so it sounds strange. You are trying to drag and drop pixels???

Comment: @Gustavo Carvalho thanks, yeah I know it sounds strange. Actually as mentioned we are trying to use much bigger screen (tiled display walls).

Comment: You realize my skepticism, right? It's not a common use of canvas either. You would avoided some trouble(down votes) if you had explained your later comments in your original post. Nevertheless this discussion became very constructive. Many thanks to markE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really haven’t given many details

These questions quickly come to mind:

- Are dots the same size?
- Are dots uniformly disbursed on the canvas?
- If one dot is “selected”, is only that one dot recolored or moved?
- Why are you violating good data visualization rules by overwhelming the user? :)

With this lack of specificity in mind...

...Divide and conquer:

- Divide your dot array into multiple parts.
- Divide your dots onto multiple overlaying canvases.

**Divide your dot array into multiple parts**

This will allow you to examine far fewer array elements when searching for the 1 you need.

Create a container object with 1980 elements representing the 1980 “x” coordinates on the screen.

```
var container={};

for(var x=1;x<=1980;x++){
    container[x]=[];
}
```

Each container element is an array of dot objects with their dot centers on that x-coordinate.

Every dot object has enough info to locate and redraw itself.

A dot at x-coordinate == 125 might be defined like this:

```
{x:125,y:100,r:2,color:"red",canvas:1};
```

When you want to add a dot, push a dot object to the appropriate "x" element of the container object.

```
// add a dot with x screen coordinate == 952
container[952].push({x:952,y:100,r:2,color:"red",canvas:1});
```

Dots can be drawn based on the dot objects:

```
function drawDot(dot,context){
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle=dot.color;
    context.arc(dot.x,dot.y,dot.r,0,PI2,false);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
}
```

When the user selects a dot, you can find it quickly by pulling the few container elements around the X where the user clicked:

```
function getDotsNearX(x,radius){

    // pull arrays from "x" plus/minus "radius"
    var dotArrays=[]
    for(var i=x-radius;i<=x+radius;i++){
        dotArrays.push(container[i]);
    }
    return(dotArray);
}
```

Now you can process the dots in these highly targeted arrays instead of all 5 million array elements.

When the user moves a dot to a new position, just pull the dot object out of its current container element and push it into the appropriate new "x" container element.

**Divide your dots onto multiple overlaying canvases**

To improve drawing performance, you will want to disburse your dots across multiple canvas overlayed on each other.

The dot element includes a canvas property to identify on which canvas this dot will be drawn.

Comment: +1 very nice approach. But you agree that 5 million objects is a disturbing number, don't you?

Comment: @GustavoCarvalho:  Yes--way too many!  Ironically yesterday I watched a great data-visualization video by Billy Hollis at TechEd where he stressed that inadequate "white space" is very stressful to the user.

Comment: @markE thank you a lot! good approach and I will answer your questions: Q1. Are dots the same size? YES; Q2. Are dots uniformly disbursed on the canvas? actually yes and no. Based on user interactions, the layout of these dots are totally changed. sometimes, uniformly and sometimes not; Q3. If one dot is “selected”, is only that one dot recolored or moved? mostly yes;

Comment: @markE Q4. Why are you violating good data visualization rules by overwhelming the user? Good question. Our visualization is based on a large display wall so a visual approach may be different. we trying to  create a big image pattern which consists of very detail visual objects. so one visualization includes multi-scale information.

Comment: @markE your answer is a little bit different from others. Many people recommend me to use QuadTree. You don't recommend such method?

Comment: All spacial access methods based on tree searches are excellent for large populations.  QuadTree is particularly good at point searches but takes more effort to decompose structures like polygons and curves (dots).  RTree is particularly good at searches for polygons.  Even a simple binary search will find a starting-pair match from 5million in about 25 iterations.  Any tree search (as well as my more linear method) all use “divide and conquer” to tackle your 5MM.  These methods require different overhead (initial indexing, reindexing, memory, leaf-traversing).  Bottom line: test them all.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already taken a look at the [KineticJS](http://www.kineticjs.com) framework? There is a [very impressive stress-test](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-drag-and-drop-stress-test-with-1000-shapes/) with exactly the same drag-and-drop functionality you're looking for. If you use KineticJS, you can access every single dot with the following `eventlistener`, and of course change its color, size etc.:

```
      stage.on('mousedown', function(evt) {
        var circle = evt.targetNode;
      });
```

Comment: Thanks I already tested but it works for 10,000 dots but doesn't work very well for more than 100,000.

Comment: Well, it takes quite a while to load, but after it has completely loaded, the performance is still awesome for such a huge amount of shapes, isn't it? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/s7g6f/1/) I've tried it with 300 layers and 5000 circles each, wich makes a total of 1.500.000 shapes. It takes about 40-60 secs. to load, but after that  it works pretty well.